# The triangle inequality for shortest paths of graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, metric-spaces, topological-graph-theory

In [why-the-triangle-inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3mhd.png)

I found the statement:

> for example if $d(a,b)$ measures the "length" of the "shortest path" between points $a$ and $b$ (and this can be interpreted quite abstractly, for example if $a$ and $b$ are states of some physical system and $d(a,b)$ describes the amount of energy that needs to be expended to get from $a$ to $b$), then $d(a,c)≤d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ because an optimal "path" from $a$ to $b$, together with an optimal "path" from $b$ to $c$, can be no better than the optimal "path" from $a$ to $c$.

Until now I assumed that minimal paths do not fullfill the triangle inequality.
Does someone know, how to prove this or where to find it proved? I'm working on an thesis in informatics (graph theory) and need evidence for this statement, e.g. for minimal paths in weighted Delaunay-Graphs.

Definitions:
[image]

Maybe this is also relevant: I use Dijkstra's Shortest-Path Algorithm to calculate g(l,j)

Comment: Isn't the paragraph you quoted a proof itself?  If $U$ is a path of length (or weight) $u$ from $a$ to $b$, and $V$ is a path of length  $w$ from $b$ to $c$, then the shortest path from $a$ to $c$ cannot be longer than $u+v$, because the concatenation of paths $U$ and $V$ is itself a path from $a$ to $c$ of that length.

Comment: With the first try, I posted the question in the wrong forum: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/194917/the-triangle-inequality-for-shortest-paths-of-graphs in the last comment there, someone told me, that only in special cases the shortest path is a distance. Maybe the better question as a non mathematician would be: Which cases?

Comment: The comment there gave you a counterexample: if the edge weights are negative, a longer path can have a smaller weight. They also said the same thing I did, which is that the paragraph you quoted *is* a proof. I'm having trouble understanding what your question is.

Comment: I tried to define my problem (see above). If I have for G a Delaunay graph or a k nearest neighbour graph, does g(l,j) fullfill the triangle inequality?

Comment: If the weights are nonnegative, we have triangle inequality.